# Do person with strong immune system have less chance of surviving SARS-COV-2 attack?

Tags: immunology, coronavirus, immune-system, autoimmune, retrovirus

In most of the cases dealing with SARS-COV-2 disease, the major mortality cause is due to cytokine storm in response to Corona-virus that also attack healthy organs causing multiple organ failure.

> leading to inflammation and fluid buildup in the lungs.(*7*) Certain kinds of cytokines trigger cell death. When you have many cells doing this at the same time, a lot of tissue can die. In COVID-19, that tissue is mostly in the lung.(*5*)
>
> > Among the many mysteries of Covid-19 is why relatively healthy young people suddenly become critically ill — or die.Many otherwise robust patients were experiencing cytokine storms. One key sign of that was the body’s levels of ferritin, a protein in the body that binds to iron. This massive over-reaction, known as a cytokine storm, is believed to be a major reason that a growing number of exceedingly fit people find themselves fighting for their lives.(*7*)

Assuming healthy people having a strong immune system have greater cytokine storm against SARS-COV-2, isn't coronavirus naturally selecting people with "weaker" immune response?

However an interesting case has been observed within Haemodialytic patient(not-healthy):

> HD patients with COVID-19 even displayed more remarkable reduction of serum inflammatory cytokines than other COVID-19 patients. [Epidemiological, clinical, and immunological features of a cluster of COVID-19 contracted hemodialysis patients](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7282748/)

References:

1. https://scroll.in/article/962574/what-is-a-cytokine-storm-and-why-is-its-prevention-key-to-treating-covid-19
2. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2020/05/200521165706.htm
3. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1359610120300927
4. [The cytokine storm in COVID-19: An overview of the involvement of the chemokine/chemokine-receptor system](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10067-020-05190-5)
5. [Cytokine Storms May Be Fueling Some COVID Deaths](https://www.webmd.com/lung/news/20200417/cytokine-storms-may-be-fueling-some-covid-deaths)
6. ### [Why Some COVID-19 Patients Crash: The Body's Immune System Might Be To Blame](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2020/04/07/828091467/why-some-covid-19-patients-crash-the-bodys-immune-system-might-be-to-blame)
7. [He ran marathons and was fit. So why did Covid-19 almost kill him?](https://www.statnews.com/2020/04/21/he-ran-marathons-why-did-coronavirus-almost-kill-him/)

Comment: Is this a question or a blog post? The answer (if it is really meant as a question) may be yes (or no) but before anyone can attempt to answer it they would need to know what “a strong immune system” is (as well as its relationship to athleticism etc.). Is this something that can and has been measured, or is it something purveyed by the media and other charlatans? Perhaps you could provide references to this, or ask a separate question on this specific point (preferably to SE Medical Sciences).

Comment: @David By Strong immune system, I meant adequate immune response generated by the patient to quench the effects of pathogenic diseases. Although I didn't find any journal paper that would answer the question given in the title, I welcome any comment that would provide some key insights